# PHP version 4 :: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Tags: php, arrays, function

This function working properly with the newer PHP versions:

```
function MKDSLD($mkD,&$slD=array()){}
```

BUT

I'm getting :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
```

With PHP 4.

Needless to say that I got to solve it under the older version of PHP :)

Pretty simple but I guess small tweak is needed here :D

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Remove `= array()` and make it a required argument (I'm not even gonna ask why anyone "got to solve" this for PHP 4 in 2021). There isn't really a "simple" or "small tweak" to get the same functionality in PHP 4.

Comment: If `I got to solve it under the older version of PHP` is because you need backwards compatibility, you shouldn't be support version 4.. maybe back to 5.6. Consider https://www.php.net/eol.php, 2 years is as far back as I'd go

Answer (score 3):

PHP 4 doesn't support default parameters for reference parameters.

You should deal with `$slD` as a required argument:

```
function MKDSLD($mkD, &$slD){
    // code
}


$x = array();
MKDSLD(5, $x);
```